# Fancybox launches iframe only on the second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

By that I mean, when I click on a div, I have to click twice in order to open the fancybox iframe, but after exiting out of that iframe. But opening another on the same page, only requires 1 click.

BSN() is a function that generates a "menu"

Here is the snippet of code I think might be the issue:

```
function generateTemplateInfo(blockID) {
$.getJSON('links.json').done(function (data) {
    switch (blockID) {
    case 'bsn_traditional':
        $('#' + blockID).fancybox({
            fitToView: false
            , autoSize: false
            , autoDimensions: false
            , width: 750
            , height: 550
            , href: 'template.html'
            , type: 'iframe'
            , afterLoad: function () {
                loadData(blockID, data);
            }
        });
        break;
    case 'msn_specialist':
        $('#' + blockID).fancybox({
            fitToView: false
            , autoSize: false
            , autoDimensions: false
            , width: 750
            , height: 550
            , href: 'template.html'
            , type: 'iframe'
            , afterLoad: function () {
                loadData(blockID, data);
            }
        });
        break;
    default:
        console.log('error');
        break;
    }
     });
}

function BSN() {
    removeBlocks(); 
    generateSubMenu(2, 3, 'BSN');
    $(".navi").on('click', '.subBlocks', function () {
        generateTemplateInfo(this.id);
        });
    }
```

Comment: This `$(".selector").fancybox()` **does not** trigger fancybox, only binds fancybox to the selector. In other words, your first `click` only binds fancybox to the selector while the second triggers it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does. Do you have Any recommendation on a solution? Thanks

Comment: Add a *class* to your element(s) and bind that selector to fancybox. Then, in your `switch` statement just trigger a `click` to the target `id` (which will also have the *class* bound to fancybox)